# Is there a way in pd.read_csv to replace NaN value with other character?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some data in csv file.
Because it is collected from machine,all lines should be number but some NaN values exists in some lines.And the machine can auto replace these NaN values with a string '-'.

My question is how to set params of ***pd.read_csv()*** to auto replace '-'values with zero from csv file?

Comment: Use `fillna(0)` after reading the data. Filling the Nans while reading csv is a heavy work for the function.

Comment: All the "NaN" values have already replaced by character '-',my question is how to replace '-' with zero. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Use `df = df.where(df!='-',0)`

Comment: @Bharath or `df.replace('-', 0, inplace=True)` if you have to do it post-read...

Comment: Thanks@Bharath and @Jon Clements♦,I believe there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

while reading the `csv` file you can use the parameter [na_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',na_values='-')
```

Edit:
you can then convert nan to 0 by:

```
df.fillna(0,1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved! This is the smartest way so far I think.

Comment: The first part of the answer is wrong. `na_values` doesn't replace **NaN** values. It lets you specify additional strings to recognize as **NA/NaN**. The second part is problematic because let's say I have ints in my column, and some `NaN` values. Reading the csv normally using `read_csv` converts the ints to floats **because of the NaNs**. Then `fillna` just replaces the `NaN`s with zeros, but the floats remain. I personally wanted to avoid the ints being converted to floats.

Comment: @AlaaM. I had exactly the same issue - I have posted a solution which avoids turning integers into floats below. Probably too late for you but hopefully in time to help someone else :)

Answer (score 8):

You can try something like this :

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('somefile.txt')

df = df.fillna(0)
```

Hope that'll help !

Answer (score 2):

Putting this into the read_csv function does work:
`dtype={"count": pandas.Int64Dtype()}`

i.e.

`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')`

This type supports both integers and pandas.NA values so you can import without the floats becoming integers.

If necessary, you can then use regular DataFrame commands to clean up the missing values, as described in other answers here.

BTW, my first attempt to solve this changes the integers into strings. If that's of interest:
`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', na_filter= False)`

(It reads the file without replacing any missing values with NaN).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```py
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the NaNs after reading the csv file. For example, convert the NaNs to 0:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df.fillna(0,1,inplace=True)
```

Using the parameter [na_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), like `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', na_values='-')`, has nothing to do with this.